# How do I randomize an array full of strings? C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I searched and found some for randomizing numbers, but I don't think it applies for strings....For example I have a list like this in an array:

```
string restaurants[] = {"Texas Roadhouse,","On The Border,","Olive Garden,","Panda       Express,","Cracker Barrel,","IHOP,","Panda Express,","Pei Wei"};
```

How would I randomize this or just swap them all around and jumble them up?

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.

```
std::random_shuffle(std::begin(restaurants), std::end(restaurants));
```

In C++03, without implementing your own `begin` and `end`:

```
std::random_shuffle(restaurants, restaurants + sizeof restaurants / sizeof restaurants[0]);
```

Be aware that unless you use something such as `std::vector`, passing it into a function to do this not by reference will need to use the latter with an additional size argument.

Comment: So what would I need to include or change given I am only have #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std; in my header

Comment: @user1751615, `std::random_shuffle` is part of `<algorithm>`, along with many other *don't reinvent the wheel* functions.

Answer (score 1):

you could do like

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  static string numbers[] =  {"Texas Roadhouse,","On The Border,","Olive Garden,","Panda       Express,","Cracker Barrel,","IHOP,","Panda Express,","Pei Wei"};
  srand(time(0));
  int rand_index = rand() % 10;
  cout << numbers[rand_index] << endl;

  string input;
  getline(cin,input);
  cout << (((input=="even")==(rand_index+1)%2==0) ? "Right." : "Wrong.") << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative for fun (sort by random) :

```
std::sort(restaurants, restaurants + sizeof(restaurants) / sizeof(std::string), [](int x, int y) -> bool { return rand() % 100 >= 50; });
```

Comment: Sorry but this predicate doesn't satisfy a _strict weak ordering_ so there's no guarantee it will work correctly or not crash. There's a reason the standard library has `std::random_shuffle`.